# iPhone Screen Recording simulation on Windows

Tags: iphone, screen-capture, recording

I need to make a video of browsing websites on iPhone. I don't have a Mac so I can't make Airplay mirroring and record it there.
Is there any way to do it on Windows 10? I need to keep video resolution same as iPhone has. 
It's one time thing, freely is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program AirServer on Windows to let your iPhone AirPlay mirror to the PC in order to record the stream.

AirServer has a free 7-day trial, so for a one time thing, it could be done without paying.

Download it from here: [AirServer Download](https://www.airserver.com/Download)

Other similar programs are Reflector 2 and X-Mirage. However, Reflector 2 watermarks the video during the trial period.